# Clearing whitespace for user input data when posting to table

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to clear whitespace and add a '@' character at the beginning when the user inputs a name to post to the database.

I already have a working script to allow users to input data and modify it, but I want to include a script where the whitespace is cleared and a '@' is added before the name.

E.g. If user inputs 'John Whatsmyname' - it will be posted as - @JohnWhatsmyname in the table

I thought it would just be as simple as adding something like this;

```
$name = ($_POST['name']); 
$name = '@'.str_replace(' ', '', $name);

$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
```

Currently I have the following HTML;

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['name']; ?>" placeholder="username" name="name"/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['email']; ?>" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
```

Full PHP script:

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array('name', 'email');
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Name & email are required';
        break 1;
    }
}


$name = ($_POST['name']); 
$name = '@'.str_replace(' ', '', $name);

$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);


<?php
   if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
   echo 'Your details have been updated!'; 
    } else {
       if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

    $update_data = array(
        'info'      => $_POST['info'],
        'website'   => $_POST['website'],
        'location'  => $_POST['location'],
         $name      => $_POST['name'],
        'email'     => $_POST['email'],
    );

    update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
    header('Location: profile.php?success');
    exit();

      } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
          echo output_errors($errors);
                  }
      }
    ?>
```

I think when I am applying the changes I am doing nothing with then therefore the script continues and updates the table with the original data - I have echoed the $name variable and I get the error undefined variable.

The script needs to change the name by putting a '@' at the beginning and removes all whitespace not just the beginning and end before posting to the table. Trying to avoid error messages and have a script to fix the problem.

Thanks (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing it work because you do all the work to process `$name`, and then your `$update_data` array goes and pulls a fresh **copy** from the global `$_POST` array. Instead, you should change it to this:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : '';
if (empty($name)) 
{
    die('No name provided');
}

// Format name
$name = '@'.str_replace(' ', '', $name);

$update_data = array(
    'info'      => $_POST['info'],
    'website'   => $_POST['website'],
    'location'  => $_POST['location'],
    'name'      => $name,
    'email'     => $_POST['email'],
);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! (after making the change @Darren suggested) , and I understand now what was going wrong. Will keep a note for the future (Y)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that typo. If this answer worked for you, can please accept it? Thanks.